# jQuery( document ).ready() + wait for focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, focus

Folks,

Someone refreshes all their tabs. My tab is in a non-active non-foreground tab.

This runs: `jQuery(document).ready().`

So:

- How do I get my animation to run only when the tab becomes active?

AND

- How do I get it to run if the tab is foreground and active anyway?

I have tried:

```
<script>jQuery( document ).ready(function() { jQuery(window).focus(function () { setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('.juiz-outdated-message').addClass('active'); }, 500); }); });</script>
```

This happens on so many sites I can't find any resources on how to do it, though?!

Comment: @gurvinder372, thanks for your comment but as you can see from the code fragment in my question I've already tried that and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get it to run if the tab is foreground and active anyway?

Using the [page visibility api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API), you need to handle the `visibilitychange` *event*.

> How do I get my animation to run only when the tab becomes active?

Here is an example code from the documentation link shared.

```
function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if (document.hidden) {
    pauseSimulation();
  } else  {
    startSimulation();
  }
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);
```

Shared documentation link has other fallback given as well for different browsers, and the same has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active) in detail.

Comment: I see, thank you. So there's no 'firstfocus' or similar event. I just have to check if it's got focus in the first instance. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question using the logic of what @gurvinder372 kindly provided:

```js
function animateeeee() { //the magic function
 setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('.juiz-outdated-message').addClass('active'); }, 500);
}; 
jQuery( document ).ready(function() { //runs on DOM ready
    if (document.hasFocus()) { //if we already have focus...
     animateeeee(); //do it now
     } else { //otherwise
  jQuery(window).focus(function() { //bind to focus
   animateeeee();// then run
  });       
     }; 
 });
```